# How to use Mockito to create a mock api in scala

Tags: scala, api, unit-testing, mockito

I'm using other teams api(let's name it otherTeamAPI) to call data, so in my function, my code looks like this:

```
def getData(host:String, port:Int, date: String): Map[String, String] = {
  val data = new otherTeamAPI(host,port)
  val latestData = data.getLatestData(date)
}
```

Could someone teach me how to use Mockito to do the same thing to get `data` in unit test? I'm not sure whether to use something like below to `new an api`:

```
val otherTeamAPI = Mock[otherTeamAPI]
otherTeamAPI.getLatestData(date)
```

How to get `data` everytime i trigger my function `getData`? Do i need to do somthing new a mock `otherTeamAPI`?

Comment: I just want to get some defined `data` when everytime unit test to `new otherTeamAPI(host,port)`, that's my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, written as is, is not testable. You have to be able to pass your method an instance of the `OtherTeamAPI` so that your production code uses a real instance but test code can use a fake one (a "mock").

How you pass this instance depends on the structure of the rest of your code: either as a parameter of this method `getData` or as an attribute of the class that contains it.

The first one would look like this:

```scala
def getData(api: OtherTeamApi, date: String): Map[String, String] = {
  val latestData = api.getLatestData(date)
  // ...
}
```

And then in your test, you can do something like:

```scala
val fakeApi = mock[OtherTeamAPI]
when(fakeApi.getLatestData(anyString())).the return(...)

val result = getData(fakeApi, ...)

// Then assert on result
```

This is a high level answer. You'll need to learn more about Mockito to find out what you want to do.

Comment: A side question: is it possible to mock a constructor call? (like mocking the local val "data" from within the method under test in the example above) ? I have tried using PowerMockito.whenNew(...) but for some reason, this didn't work for me in Scala.

Comment: Thank you!! As i'm a green hand, I'm not quite understand why i can't test it in my original code? I change my code to add implicit: 
`def getData(date: String)(implicit api : OtherTeamAPI): Map[String, String] = {   
val latestData = api.getLatestData(date)   
// ... }`  
Then in my test, I change it to: 
`implicit val mockapi : OtherTeamAPI = mock[OtherTeamAPI]` `when(mockapi.getLatestData(date)).thenReturn(...)`  
But I get an error in `when(mockapi.getLatestData(date))` - Unspecified value parameters: value : Any. 
Could you help on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `api.getLatestData(date)` get back the type of `try[defined]` data

Comment: ah, i know, because `when` is using the sql package, rather than mockito, but it's strange that i cannot import `org.mockito.Mockito.when`, how can it fix it? My pom.xml is using
`<dependency>
<artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
<version>4.6.0</version>
<scope>test</scope>
<dependency>
`

Comment: this issue may due to my idea's bug....

Comment: but in `thenReturn()`, i put some something like `thenReturn(myTypeData)`, myTypeData is defined as a kind of data formate in my side, it shows error like Cannot resolve overloaded method `thenReturn`, how can i fix it?